# How to handle breaking change due to company change of name?

Tags: distribution

I maintain on behalf on my company a few Java libraries, with a small yet non-null userbase.

The powers that be have decided to change the name of the company, and while the plan is to hold onto the domain name for the foreseeable future, the company does not wish to be associated with its old name **at all**, and quickly.

The problem is that the Java packages published use the name of the company, `com.foo.awesomelib` will become `com.bar.awesomelib`.

How can I, in the most respectful way to the users, make the move?

Comment: Aren't there still some (perhaps legacy) official Java packages with names like com.sun.java.* ?  And I don't think Oracle ever had a problem with this, as I recall.

Comment: @Brandin: Big companies hardly ever have a problem with stuff like this. It's always the small and medium ones that think they have something to prove.

Comment: Unless you release a whole new lib, the name will just stick for ever, and most companies don't care (see the huge amount of Android apps with widely oudated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't speak with any particular authority on this matter, but it seems to me that a halfway house is the best approach.  Do by all means change the name going forward, but leave the old repository up and available; essentially, fork the package.

No doubt the company will wish to expunge any evidence of its old name from the historical record, but that's just tough.  Code was released with the company's name in, and the company chose to put it there.  It happened, so it's part of the historical record; the company's desire for a quick-change act doesn't invalidate history.  Perhaps the company will learn a thing or to from this about using java package names as a *sub rosa* form of advertising.

If you try to remove the packages under their old name from wherever it is they are currently distributed, and assuming they were distributed under a free licence, someone else in the user community may well put them back, and they'd be well entitled to do so.  Such a bad faith act also makes it *more* likely, to my mind, that the community will continue development under the old naming scheme, instead of adopting the name change going forward.